# onBindViewHolder doesnt recognize viewholder widgets

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

im creating a project that needs a horizontal recyclerview in adapter class i have a problem with ViewHolder, its my code :

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{


private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> imageUrls = new ArrayList<>();
private Context mContext;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mNames, ArrayList<String> imageUrls) {
    this.mNames = mNames;
    this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem,viewGroup,false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    Glide.with(mContext)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(imageUrls.get(i))
            .into(viewHolder.image);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mNames.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView image;
    TextView name;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_overlay);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    }
}
```

}

my problem is that .into(viewHolder.image) is returning an error :
Error:(47, 33) error: cannot find symbol variable image

what should i do?

Comment: post your layout_listitem.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> imageUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mNames, ArrayList<String> imageUrls) {
        this.mNames = mNames;
        this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(imageUrls.get(i))
                .into(viewHolder.image);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNames.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
        TextView name;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_overlay);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you wrote `extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>` instead of `extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>` in other words you should pass your ViewHolder class instead of standard from RecyclerView

also I changed onCreateViewHolder() and onBindViewHolder() signatures so it now returns and receives your ViewHolder instead of RecyclerView.ViewHolder